Why is tz-naive Timestamp converted to integer while tz-aware is kept as Timestamp?
Understandable and expected (tz-aware):
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

aware = pd.DatetimeIndex(["2024-11-21", "2024-11-21 12:00"], tz="UTC")
eod = datetime.datetime.combine(aware[-1].date(), datetime.time.max, aware.tz)
aware, eod, np.concat([aware, [eod]])

returns
(DatetimeIndex(['2024-11-21 00:00:00+00:00', '2024-11-21 12:00:00+00:00'],
               dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', freq=None),
 datetime.datetime(2024, 11, 21, 23, 59, 59, 999999,
                   tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
 array([Timestamp('2024-11-21 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
        Timestamp('2024-11-21 12:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
        datetime.datetime(2024, 11, 21, 23, 59, 59, 999999,
                          tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)],
       dtype=object))

note Timestamps (and a datetime) in the return value of np.concat.
Unexpected (tz-naive):
naive = pd.DatetimeIndex(["2024-11-21", "2024-11-21 12:00"])
eod = datetime.datetime.combine(naive[-1].date(), datetime.time.max, aware.tz)
naive, eod, np.concat([naive, [eod]])

returns
(DatetimeIndex(['2024-11-21 00:00:00', '2024-11-21 12:00:00'],
               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None),
 datetime.datetime(2024, 11, 21, 23, 59, 59, 999999),
 array([1732147200000000000, 1732190400000000000,
        datetime.datetime(2024, 11, 21, 23, 59, 59, 999999)], dtype=object))

note intergers (and a datetime) in the return value of np.concat.

why do I get integers in the concatenated array for a tz-naive index?
how do I avoid it? I.e., how do I append EOD to a tz-naive DatetimeIndex?

PS. Interestingly enough, at the numpy level the indexes are identical:
np.testing.assert_array_equal(aware.values, naive.values)


My assumption would be for efficiency for deltas between timestamps without going through an additional correction layer. Basically a fast path. Be interesting to see the technical answer

@roganjosh: I am not sure what "efficiency" could be accomplished here. Looks like a bug, TBH.

Because it's just integer subtraction without having to modify the integers beforehand with some offset. A non-naive date time has to carry metadata that will require a non-vectorized handling before a delta could be calculated

I've go a different representation of the concatenated array concat: [1732147200000000000 1732190400000000000  datetime.datetime(2024, 11, 21, 23, 59, 59, 999999, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/New_York' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>)] . I think it's for compatibility, it's the only representation that has implicit and explicit tz information.

Explicit casting of eod (naive example; naive, eod, np.concat([naive, [np.datetime64(eod)]])) would leave you with a np.datetime64 data type array. In general, it seems to me a lot of the trouble comes from mixing libraries that handle datetime differently. Why not go pandas-only?

@FObersteiner: how would you define eod?

Maybe aware[-1].ceil("d")-pd.Timedelta(nanoseconds=1) (adjust the timedelta as needed, 1 ns is just the minimum possible). If you wish to keep a datetime index with eod you could probably use union; aware.union([eod]) in the example.

@FObersteiner - the same problem as with my code - concatenated array has integers instead of dates

(additionally, ceil(d) may return the same date as the current date!) --- but thanks for the pointer!

right, I noted that as well - probably something like eod = (aware[-1] + pd.Timedelta(1)).floor("d") - pd.Timedelta(nanoseconds=1). numpy's casting behavior seems just weird to me, tbh. I'd probably try to use a pd.DatetimeIndex or a pd.Series instead of np array, but that is of course depending on application requirements.

From Data type promotion in NumPy

When mixing two different data types, NumPy has to determine the appropriate dtype for the result of the operation. This step is referred to as promotion or finding the common dtype.
In typical cases, the user does not need to worry about the details of promotion, since the promotion step usually ensures that the result will either match or exceed the precision of the input.

np.concat() accepts a casting keyword argument (casting="same_kind" default).
If using casting='no' fails
naive_no = np.concat([naive, [eod]], casting='no')

TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('<M8[ns]') to dtype('O') according to the rule 'no'

See Array-protocol type strings.
In both cases the type is object
naive_sk = np.concat([naive, [eod]], casting='same_kind')
print(naive_sk.dtype, naive_sk)

Result
object [1732147200000000000 1732190400000000000
 datetime.datetime(2024, 11, 21, 23, 59, 59, 999999, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/New_York' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>)]

python 3.9
pandas 2.2.2

Two things that still bug me about np's casting rule - 1) "precision": There's no gain in precision here. IMHO an int has less meaning when derived from datetime, so we actually loose something (rule violated ?!). If the least common denominator is 'object', why not keep the original dtypes? 2) casting to a common dtype still fails if you use naive pd.Timestamp and datetime.datetime - which could both be casted safely to np.datetime64 !

@FObersteiner as I see it 1) the docs say "match or exceed". A naive object converted to a unix ts (int) carries the same precision of the datetime object as both define a time with nanoseconds. 2) a naive datetime casted to np.datetime64 is still a naive object.

for 1) datetime ≠ Unix time / integer (going from having info in a type system to having info in some optional metadata in your program "this int represents a datetime"), and 2) sure, my point is why it is not casted if casting would be perfectly fine. So no, not satisfied ^^ (this is not a critique of your answer btw.!)


The key words here seems to be precision and numerical python: numpy. My guess (guess lol) is that the cast is ok to numpy as long as the numerical precision is preserved. In other words, naive or aware a date is in the end a number to numpy.

